# clientgen generated PortType_Stub cannot be cast to javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider

Tags: java, web-services, client, jax-ws, jax-rpc

While trying to access a webservice through a client, I am not able to get the requestContext. I am trying to access the requestContext like this:

```
QuerySysStatService querySystem=new QuerySysStatService_Impl(wsdl);
QuerySysStatPortType qport=querySystem.getQuerySysStatPortType();
Map<String, Object> rContext =((BindingProvider)qport).getRequestContext();
```

But when I execute:

> ((BindingProvider) qport)

I get:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   **com.demo.client.service.QuerySysStatPortType_Stub cannot be cast to javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider**

Any suggestions / help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found that:

- `((javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider) qport)` can safely be called on WSDL interfaces generated with **JAX-WS** (by `wsimport`)
- `((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) qport)` can safely be called on **JAX-RPC** clients (created by `clientgen`)

In my case I created the WSDL interfaces with `clientgen` (JAX-RPC), so the properties could be set as below:

```
javax.xml.rpc.Stub stub = (javax.xml.rpc.Stub) qport;
stub._setProperty("KEY","Value");
```