# Class Cast Exception for Binding Provider

Tags: java, soap, header, client

I created SOAP Client and i need to pass the SOAP request with the Secuity header in java,
I followed this article
https://victorjabur.com/2014/11/03/how-to-consume-a-webservice-that-uses-ws-security-authentication-usernametoken-owsm-oracle-service-bus-osb/
In my code i'm using following code
`Proxy p=new Proxy();

Port port=p.getPort();

BindingProvider provider=(BindingProvider)port;`

But i'm getting
 ClassCastException: Stub cannot be cast to BinderProvider
I dont see any automatic generated classes implementing BindingProvider or WSBindingProvider, is this the exact problem for unable to cast?
Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Can you show your code by editing the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clientgen generated PortType\_Stub cannot be cast to javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946284/clientgen-generated-porttype-stub-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-xml-ws-bindingprovider)

Comment: @Rao - what do you mean by duplicate ? didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

Setting this property may solve:

`System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext", "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory");`

or jvm parameter

-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContext=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

Comment: Still facing the issue, i didn't metion in the question, but the proxy class i'm using doesn't implement BindingProvider class, not whether this is the real cause.